# SSIS Redirect Request Failed Error

Tags: redirect, reporting-services, ssis

I have an SSIS package that calls an SSRS report hosted on a local server that produces a series of PDFs. It has been working perfectly for months, but all of the sudden I am now getting this error:

Error: 0xC001600B at SSIS_Package, Connection manager "ReportServer": The specified server, URL http://server/report&parameter1=401&parameter2=13&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF, has a redirect and the redirect request failed.

I have checked all my credentials in the package and on the server and everything is connected properly. I haven't been able to find anything at all about this error and I'm hoping someone out there has come across it!

Comment: Are there any errors in your SSRS logs?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a permissions error that was resolved by another user running the package.